# Как на python с библиотекой pygame сделать так чтобы персонаж мог стрелять вверх, вниз, влево, вправо?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("game lupa, tank")
bg = pygame.image.load('images\\bg.jpg')
player = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_left.png')
player_left = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_left.png')
player_rigth = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_rigth.png')
player_down = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_down.png')
player_up = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_up.png')
patron1 = pygame.image.load('images\\patron1.png')
width = 60
height = 55
x = 250
y = 400
speed = 3
lastMove = 'right'
UDMove = 'up'
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bullets = []
bullets1 = []
class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x + 10
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius - 1
        self.facing = facing
        self.color = color
        self.vel = 10 * facing
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
def drawWindow():
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
runGame = True
while runGame:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if lastMove == 'right':
            facing = 1
        elif lastMove == 'left':
            facing = -1
        elif UDMove == 'up':
            upfacing = 1
        elif UDMove == 'down':
            upfacing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 10:
            bullets.append(snaryad(round(x + width // 2), round(y + height // 2), 8, (0, 0, 255), facing))
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 1:
        x -= speed
        player = player_rigth
        lastMove = 'left'
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 450:
        x += speed
        player = player_left
        lastMove = 'right'
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 1:
        y -= speed
        player = player_up
        UDMove = 'up'
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450:
        y += speed
        player = player_down
        UDMove = 'down'
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    drawWindow()
    win.blit(player, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Я смог сделать только так чтобы он стрелял вверх и вниз или влево и вправо. А всё вместе я не смог

Comment: Вы пишете  `стрелять сразу вверх, вниз, влево, вправо?`
 Допустим, у игрока есть одно оружие. Как вы себе представляете, что оно стреляет сразу в 4 стороны?

Comment: я перепутал, я не могу сделать так, чтобы он стрелял либо верх, вниз, влево, вправо.

Comment: Приведите  "Самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).


У вас не определено имя clock (`clock = pygame.time.Clock()`), не инициализирован дисплей (`pygame.init()`), не определён bullets и win, далее я не смотрел

Comment: явная ошибка - повтор в строках:

  elif UDMove == 'up':
            upfacing = 1
        elif UDMove == 'up':
            upfacing = -1

И да - желателен полный код для проведения отладки

Comment: в строке:  elif UDMove == 'up':
            upfacing = -1
замените 'up' на 'down'

Comment: нет, не в этом проблема. Мне надо сделать так чтобы персонаж смог стрелять ещё вверх и вниз, а не только в влево и вправо. заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("game lupa, tank")
bg = pygame.image.load('images\\bg.jpg')
player = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_left.png')
player_left = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_left.png')
player_rigth = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_rigth.png')
player_down = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_down.png')
player_up = pygame.image.load('images\\tank_player_up.png')
patron1 = pygame.image.load('images\\patron1.png')
width = 60
height = 55
x = 250
y = 400
speed = 3
lastMove = 'right'
UDMove = 'up'
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bullets = []
bullets1 = []
class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing, upf):
        self.upf = upf
        self.x = x + 10 if upf in ['left','right'] else x
        self.y = y if upf in ['left','right'] else y + 10
        self.radius = radius - 1
        self.facing = facing
        self.color = color
        self.vel = 10 * facing
    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
def drawWindow():
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
runGame = True
while runGame:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.upf in ['left','right'] and bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        elif bullet.upf in ['up','down'] and bullet.y < 500 and bullet.y > 0:
            bullet.y += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if lastMove == 'right':
            facing = 1
        elif lastMove == 'left':
            facing = -1
        elif lastMove == 'up':
            facing = -1
        elif lastMove == 'down':
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) < 10:
            bullets.append(snaryad(round(x + width // 2), round(y + height // 2), 8, (0, 0, 255), facing, lastMove))
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 1:
        x -= speed
        player = player_rigth
        lastMove = 'left'
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 450:
        x += speed
        player = player_left
        lastMove = 'right'
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 1:
        y -= speed
        player = player_up
        lastMove = 'up'
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450:
        y += speed
        player = player_down
        lastMove = 'down'
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    drawWindow()
    win.blit(player, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Код можно немного сократить, но с этим думаю сами справитесь

Comment: Кстати, не рекомендую сильно увлекаться pygame)
Захотите что-то стоящее сделать и появятся проблемы с оптимизацией, я так пару месяцев в пустую потратил)

Comment: спасибо, мне просто надо игру доделать.